# CNTLM won't work on CentOS 7

Tags: centos-7, cntlm

CNTLM RPM was installed properly.  The service is configured and seems running fine:

```
[user@centos~]$ sudo service cntlmd status
Checking for CNTLM Authentication Proxy: ● cntlmd.service - LSB: start/stop the cntlm proxy
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/cntlmd)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-09-07 13:14:45 BST; 2min 53s ago
```

But I don't have any network connectivity: yum and curl both fail with the same message:

```
Failed connect to localhost:3128; Connection refused
```

There are more info in `journalctl`:

```
Sep 07 13:09:47 centos cntlm[6283]: Starting cntlm version 0.92.3 for LITTLE endian
Sep 07 13:09:47 centos cntlm[6283]: Proxy listening on 0.0.0.0:3128
Sep 07 13:09:47 centos cntlm[6283]: Workstation name used: centos
Sep 07 13:09:47 centos cntlm[6283]: Using following NTLM hashes: NTLMv2(1) NT(0) LM(0)
Sep 07 13:09:47 centos cntlm[6284]: Daemon ready
Sep 07 13:09:47 centos cntlm[6284]: Changing uid:gid to 987:982 - Success
Sep 07 13:09:47 centos cntlm[6284]: Error creating a new PID file
Sep 07 13:09:47 centos cntlmd[6275]: Starting CNTLM Authentication Proxy: [  OK  ]
```

So apparently cntlm can't create its pid file...  What can I do ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This [centos.org's post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=230529#p230529) saved me.  The solution is simply to allow cntlm to create its pid file:

```
$ mkdir /var/run/cntlm
$ chgrp cntlm /var/run/cntlm/
$ chmod g+w /var/run/cntlm/
$ service cntlmd restart
```